# "As usual" versus "As always" versus "As per usual"

Tags: phrase-requests

I have a dialogue:

> -What are you both doing now?
>   -It's 6 pm, so we do English lessons as always.

But I don't want to use "as always" here as it gives the answer a passive aggressive tone. I want it to look very casual, but I'm not sure what's the difference between "As per usual" and "As usual"?

Please advise.

Comment: As with the answer provided, there is nothing to distinguish between any of the phrases. None of them, on their own, suggest passive-aggression; that's conveyed through tone of voice, not by the word choice. The choice of phrase is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 2):

'As always' does not necessarily imply passive-aggression, although it may do when spoken in a sarcastic tone. This is also true of 'as per usual' which is very British, informal, and conversational, and of 'as always'.